# Which is the correct syntax for redirecting domains using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Without **$** dollar sign

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.111\.111\.111 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

With **$** dollar sign

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.111\.111\.111$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So I want to redirect all traffic to the new domain with the same URL.
For example:

```
http://olddomain.net/post-123/
http://olddomain.org/post-123/
```

to

```
http://www.newdomain.com/post-123/
```

So which one is correct? with or without a **$** sign?

Comment: This has nothing to do at all with _syntax_ , both forms are syntactically correct. It is a question of what you actually want to match, so of _semantics_ ...

Answer (score 1):

The correct version is the version with $
Because the $ indicates precisely the end of the string.

with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.111\.111\.11
```

You also redirect 11.111.111.11**2** or 11**3** or 11**999999**
not with $ in the end.
However with all the values of your example, it should not change anything

To be really correct, you must also add `\` before the points, otherwise it could be replaced by letter or other sign. But once again, it does not change anything in this case ...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain\.com$ [NC]
```